# C# MVC Debug which controller returned view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging

So I just started at a new company and I'm trying to understand their code and it is quite complex. I am trying to debug a page and I know which view it is and I can set a break point in the view but I can't figure out which controller returned this view. How can I do this?

Recap: I can break in a view and I need to figure out what controller it came from.

Answer (score 2):

If the application is using the Razor view engine (`.cshtml` files) you can use the following inside your view/layout to display the controller and action names:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
```

If it is using the WebForms view engine (`.aspx` files) you can do something similar with:

```
<%= RouteData.Values["controller"]%>
<%= RouteData.Values["action"]%>
```

The controller class will usually be named as in the route data plus "Controller". The action names will usually match a method name in the controller.

You may also consider getting a branch of the project just for you, and then install [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) via Nuget. That may help you understand better the application.

Answer (score 0):

Views usually are named after Controller action names. And views are placed in folders named after controllers.

Check this one for folder structure: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492833/ASP-NET-MVC-4-Part-2-Project-Items

Also you can set breakpoints in controllers and see which one is hit.

And I recommend watching [free pluralsight course on MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight). I helped me a lot when I started with MVC.